# Python Flask wont accept File or Form Data

Tags: javascript, python, forms, flask, https

I'm building a Python web server using Flask with a standard HTML frontend. For my application, I need to send a file *and* a form in the same request. As I have been told to do online, I set the Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data` in order to tell Flask to expect it. For some reason, however, I cannot access the data using the request object. Either it throws an error or returns null.

```py
@app.route("/paid", methods=["POST"])
def paid():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.dumps(request.form['text_unput']) # crashes with http error 400
```

Snippet of the javascript code making the request:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("text_unput", data);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://route/to/server/paid");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
console.log(formData);
xhr.send(formData); // error 400
```

I figured out that request.data *does* work; however, because part of it is a file, and I need the rest as a string to get JSON from it, the bytes returned by request.data aren't going to cut it.

`request.form` returns null
`request.json` crashes

I've been pouring over my code looking for a mistake but it feels like Flask just doesn't pick up the file or the form data. I've gotten this to work before, so I know it's possible. I apologize if I didn't format this question correctly; this is my first one.

Comment: Please show us the actual error from the web server logs.

Comment: It doesn't give me a proper error, which is annoying. It just stops and returns error 400. Here's my proxy picking that up: `127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2024 02:53:54] "POST /paid HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Comment: How do you know the error happens on the `json.dumps()` call?

Comment: Are you sure `request.form['text_unput']` is something that will work with `json.dumps()` ?

Comment: I tested it by printing before and after each call; i have also tried printing `request.form` by itself and got an empty dictionary. It's a lot like Flask just doesnt pick up the data.

Comment: For anyone having a similar problem, I solved this by just removing `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');`. Apparently JS handles the headers for you, and messing with them will sometimes break your header so some servers can't see the data.